# Interface to comunicate with virtual qemu-kvm machine

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization

I am starting virtual machine with command:

```
/usr/bin/qemu-kvm -M pc-0.15 -cpu core2duo -smp 2 -m 2048 -name something -hda /path/to/disk.img -net nic -net user
```

This machine get IP 10.0.2.15/24

It's strange, that I can make SSH connection from virtual to host via IP 10.0.2.2. But I cannot even ping from host to virtual machine.

How to make proper connection? Thank you

Comment: Are both machines in the same network?

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably a firewall problem on one of the systems. You can use tcpdump to check whether packets are not sent at all or discarded by the recipient system:

```
tcpdump -i br0 -n host 10.0.2.15 and host 10.0.2.2
```

The problem should be discernible from this output (both systems), too:

```
iptables -L -nv
```

For testing you may disable the firewall on the VM (and on the host if that didn't solve the problem).